# Suppressing left-side continuation arrows in emacs on Windows 7

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 22.3 on Windows 7, launched via runemacs.exe (not from a shell command line).  Lines that are too long for the window wrap (good!), with an arrow glyph at the end of the line (I'm used to '\', but ok) -- and also with a matching arrow glyph at the beginning of the wrapped line.  I've not seen that left-side arrow before and I'm finding it distracting.  How do I get rid of it?

This appears in all modes (so far).  The word "wrap" does not appear in my .emacs file, which is pretty lightweight (mostly font sizes/colors and key mappings).  I've searched Google and found plenty of advice about how to turn off line-wrap, but that's not what I want.  I just want a different visual rendering of line-wrap.

I noticed, while removing .emacs entirely to verify that nothing there is to blame, that by default the thin "columns" where these arrows appear are a slightly different background color than the main window.  In my configuration I've set background and foreground colors and those apply to this part of the UI too.  A solution that changes the background color under the arrows would probably also work; my problem is that they appear to be part of the text to me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you may want to [upgrade your Emacs](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/). Version 22.3 is positively ancient!

Comment: The last pre-built public release for Windows is:  `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip` -- here is the link:  http://reflection.oss.ou.edu/gnu/gnu/emacs/windows/

Comment: Chris has a good point -- you might want to try `M-x describe-variable RET fringe-indicator-alist RET` and see if your ancient version of Emacs even has that variable built-in to the C source code.

Comment: @Chris thanks, good point -- just installed the newer version.  That wasn't the cause of this problem, but it's still a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(setq-default visual-line-fringe-indicators nil)

(setq-default fringe-indicator-alist '(
  (truncation left-arrow right-arrow)
  (continuation nil right-curly-arrow) ;; left-curly-arrow
  (overlay-arrow . right-triangle)
  (up . up-arrow)
  (down . down-arrow)
  (top top-left-angle top-right-angle)
  (bottom bottom-left-angle bottom-right-angle top-right-angle top-left-angle)
  (top-bottom left-bracket right-bracket top-right-angle top-left-angle)
  (empty-line . empty-line)
  (unknown . question-mark)))
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE** method when using `visual-line-mode` defined in `simple.el`:

```
(setq visual-line-fringe-indicators '(nil right-curly-arrow)) ;; left-curly-arrow
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, neither of those seems to have changed anything for me -- still getting the left-side indicators.  (Just saw the edit to the alternative -- if that's not part of the default config then I'm not using it.)

Comment: Or just turn off fringe altogether (as I do). ;-)

Comment: If the first solution is not working for you, and if you are *not* using `visual-line-mode`, then perhaps it would be wise to search your user configuration files and third-party libraries for `fringe-indicator-alist` -- you might have a setting that is conflicting.  Of course, you should restart Emacs after adding / modifying the code in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about fringe-indicator-alist (I didn't know this was called "fringe" before).  And yes I know a restart is needed.

Comment: Ah . . . -- the `describe-variable` revealed that `fringe-indicator-alist` . . . "*[a]utomatically becomes buffer-local when set*", so, I'll add a `setq-default` and revise the answer.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, with `setq-default` it works (but without it didn't work in 24.3 either).  Thanks!

Comment: Glad we got it all sorted out.  :)

Comment: Stack Overflow to the rescue -- thanks for making my first question a success.